# Get the average of the first’s N elements in a query LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I’m stuck in silly thing but don’t know how to do it, whenever I want to get the average of a column without retrieving all the data from de database I just run the following code:

```
Result::where('test_id', $test->id)->avg('grade')
```

The answer for a particular example is 37, now when I want to get the first 10 rows, I will run this:

```
Result::select('grade')->where('test_id', $test->id)
       ->orderBy('grade', 'asc')->limit(10)->get();
```

This off course will give me the first 10 rows, and if I use a calculator and get the average of the grades I will get 33, but if I run the following I:

```
Result::where('test_id', $test->id)->orderBy('grade','asc')->limit(10)->avg('grade');
```

I get the same 37 as with the total dataset. I'm pretty sure it is a silly thing but I can’t figure out what it is.

Comment: I edited the curly quotes off of that last 'grade' string, because I'm assuming if that was in your actual code, you'd get a parse error rather than 37.

Comment: yep, it is Ok in the actual code (a copy paste problem), Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm kind of guessing, because I'm not set up to test this right now, but what I'm thinking is, you're using the [builder `avg` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#aggregates), which does an SQL aggregate function, and the `limit(10)` is being applied after the aggregation has already happened and there's only one row anyway.

I think if you do `avg` after you get the limited results, then you'll be using the [collection `avg` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-avg) instead, and averaging over the 10 rows the query returned.

```
Result::where('test_id', $test->id)
        ->orderBy('grade','asc')->limit(10)->get()->avg('grade');
```

Comment: Well, that indeed solve the problem, Thanks a Lot, anyway, just one more question, when I try it with a pretty large data set, just for using the get() method, won't the things get a little bit slow and it uses a lot of memory??.

Comment: Yes. For only ten items, it probably won't make too much difference, but for much more than that, I'd definitely try to figure out a way to get the database to do it.

Comment: I think it would involve making a subquery to get the limited set and then doing the avg on that, but unfortunately I'm a bit rusty with the Laravel query builder, so I don't know how to do it off the top of my head.